# Area between curves finding pressure

Tags: definite-integrals

The region |$y|>3|x|$ for $0<y<1$ forms a triangle.If pressure $p(x,y)=3x^2y+4$ acts on this what's the net force and moment (about $x$ axis)

I solved this by splitting the mod function and getting the equations as $y-3x$ and $y+3x$. Can the pressure be found by a double integral from $(-1/3,1)$ to $(1/3,1)$ and then subtracting the area of the smaller triangles?

Comment: So instead of doing two integrals, you want to do three?

Comment: yeah.Is there a way to get it using 2?

Comment: $\int_{-1/3}^0dx\int_{-3x}^1dyp(x,y)+\int_0^{1/3}dx\int_{3x}^1dyp(x,y)$